# 2730 unread emails

Tags: ios, mobile-mail

I have an iPhone 6+ and my mail icon shows 2730 unread emails. When I go into email, there aren't any unread emails, let alone 2730. I have no idea how to find them to remove the alert saying I have unread email. Can you help?

Comment: Are you running the latest iOS available? Have you tried restarting your iPhone? Have you tried emptying the trash in your email client?

Comment: How is your iPhone accessing the mail server - via IMAP or POP? If via IMAP, can you see any unread messages in folders other than the inbox? Perhaps going to the webmail site for your provider can give you an idea of if there are messages anywhere that are unread.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not specify what you've already tried (if anything)?

There can be a number of causes for this problem, and many possible solutions. For now I'll offer a couple of easier solutions since I don't know what you've already tried.

**Solution 1 - Just remove Mail notifications altogether**

If all you want to do is remove the *alert*, then follow these steps:

1. Go to your iPhone Settings
2. Tap on Notifications
3. Swipe up until you see the Mail app listed
4. Tap on Mail
5. Disable the *Allow Notifications* toggle
6. Exit Settings

Now the incorrect tally of unread emails is gone.

If you want to keep the notification, but just want it 'fixed', then there are a lot of possible solutions. I offer one of the more common ones below:

**Solution 2 - Temporarily switch off your email account(s)**

1. Go to your iPhone Settings
2. Swipe up until you see Mail
3. Tap on Mail
4. Tap on Accounts
5. Select the mail account that shows the unread messages
6. Toggle the *Account* off
7. Fully switch off your iPhone by holding down the power button for about 5 seconds and swiping the *slide to power off* prompt
8. Wait for at least 30 seconds
9. Switch your iPhone back on
10. Follow Steps 1 to 5 again and then skip to Step 11 below
11. Toggle the *Account* on again

Now check whether your Unread Email count is correct?

**NOTE**

If solution 1 is **not** what you want to do, and Solution 2 does not resolve your issue, there are many other possible solutions. Please update your question to include what else (if anything) you've already tried. Also include how many email accounts you have set up on your iPhone and whether or not an iCloud email address is one of them. By doing this I (or someone else) will be able to offer further advice.

Answer (score 1):

Open your emails, I chose “all inboxes”.  Go to “edit”, mark all messages as “unread”, then go back and mark them all as “read”.  Number count cleared, but I still have my read messages that I chose to keep in my email accounts.
Just figured this out after 2+ years :(
Dvdn though these phantom emails don’t show on my list they cleared.